# Unable to SSH a script of bash commands via expect

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I'm attempting to push a single set of commands to multiple remote hosts. I can use the following on an individual basis:
`ssh user@remoteHost "bash -s" <./commands.sh`
I can put this into a loop, but then I'm stuck typing in the password n number of times. Disabling the password prompts in the SSH config files is not an option for me.
I've attempted to use expect within a loop, but I'm unable to get it working.

```
#!/bin/bash  
HOSTS="host1 host2"  
read -sp "Password: " PASSWORD  
for HOST in $HOSTS; do  
    expect -c "  
    spawn /usr/bin/ssh user@$HOST "bash -s" <./commands.sh  
    expect_before {
        "*yes/no*" {send "yes"\r;exp_continue}}
    expect {
        "*Password*" {send $PASSWORD\r;interact}}
    exit"
done
```

I get the following error:

```
spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@host1 bash  
expect: invalid option -- 's'  
usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]  
spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@host2 bash  
expect: invalid option -- 's'  
usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]
```

Any ideas? It appears as though expect is trying to interpret the bash commands. I'm unsure how to stop this.

Comment: The first `"` in `"bash -s"` ends your `expect` script too early.  Change `"` to `\"` throughout your expect script (from the `spawn` line to the `exit ` line.

Comment: "... is not an option." Were you told "password authentication is required", or do you just not know how to use public key authentication?

Comment: I changed my line of code containing the ssh command to the following and everything worked.  
`spawn sh -c {ssh root@$HOST 'bash -ls' < /tmp/commands.sh}`

Comment: @mike, you should provide an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: @cxw I tried that earlier, but then the script attempts to look for "command.sh" on the remote machine. Checkout my solution, and thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @chepner I'm aware of publics keys, and believe me I would have used them if I could. It's just restrictions based around my job.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the heads up. I took care of it.

Comment: Did you change the double quotes in the rest of the expect code?

Comment: @glennjackman No I only changed the single line I laid forth in the solution. I added in my full working code for clarification.  Also, it won't let me accept my solution as correct for another 2 days, just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
replace
`spawn /usr/bin/ssh user@$HOST "bash -s" <./commands.sh`
with
`spawn sh -c {ssh root@$HOST 'bash -ls' < /tmp/commands.sh}`
Final Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="host1 host2"

read -sp "Password: " PASSWORD

for HOST in $HOSTS; do
        expect -c "
                spawn sh -c {ssh root@$HOST 'bash -ls' < /tmp/commands.sh}
                expect_before {
                "*yes/no*" {send "yes"\r;exp_continue}}
                expect {
                "*assword*" {send $PASSWORD\r;interact}}
                exit"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
hosts=(host1 host2)
read -sp "Password: " password  
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do  
    env h="$host" p="$password" expect <<'END_EXPECT'
        spawn sh -c "/usr/bin/ssh user@$env(h) 'bash -s' <./commands.sh"
        expect {
            "*yes/no*"   {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
            "*Password*" {send "$env(p)\r"}
        }
        interact
END_EXPECT
done
```

notes

- uses lower case variable names: leave upper case varnames for the shell's use
- uses a quoted heredoc to contain the expect code

  - that lets you use single and double quotes within expect without having to worry about quoting hell in the shell
- uses `env` to pass shell variables to expect via the environment
- simplifies your expect statement

The danger with using

```
expect -c " ...; expect "*Password*" ..."
```

is that the inner double quotes get matched with the outer quotes, and are removed by the shell. That leaves `*Password*` as a bare glob that the shell can expand based on the files in your current directory and the shell settings. For example, create a file named "The Password" (with a space) and you'll get an 
error.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It's not throwing any errors, but it appears as though it's not connecting to my hosts correctly. I've tried a number of small tweaks without any success.

Comment: run it with `expect -d` to see debugging output to make sure the variables are being passed in properly.

Comment: I compared both of our code's output with debug on like you suggested. Your code sends the password to spawn_id exp4, but then gets an eof from spawn_id exp0. My code gets both of those messages from spawn_id exp4. I think that is what is causing the problem.